# Are getters the same for all properties in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

This simple question is bugging me. Are getters the same for

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name 

- (NSString*) name{
    return name;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as the other answers state, the getters are the same. The options `retain`, `copy`, and `assign` determine how to generate setters, but not the names even of those.

If you want to use a different getter name, for instance if you have a `BOOL` such as the `UIApplication` property `idleTimerDisabled`, then you do this by specifically assigned the getter name:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isIdleTimerDisabled) BOOL idleTimerDisabled
```

Without an override such as this, the getter name is always the property name.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2)

> A property declaration, however, provides additional information about
>   how the accessor methods are implemented (as described in “Property
>   Declaration Attributes”).

Both the getter and the setter behavior are defined by property declarations. In your example that is correct since it is defined `nonatomic` but if `nonatomic` were missing from the declaration it would would be implemented similar to this

```
- (NSString*) name{
    [_internal lock]; // lock using an object-level lock
    id result = [[name retain] autorelease];
    [_internal unlock];
    return result;
}
```

This of course is only true if you use `@synthesize` and do not override or change the getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same. `retain`, `copy`, and `assign` only give the compiler instructions on how to generate setters, not getters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `copy` and `retain` only affect the setter and not the getter. On a side note, you should chose `copy` instead of `retain` for immutable objects like `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ARC (Automated Reference Counting), then the getters should all look like what you have above. However, the new standard with ARC is to use `strong` and `weak` instead of `retain` and `assign`, respectively. `retain` and `assign` will still work and are synonymous with the `strong` and `weak`, but any newly generated files will use those words instead, so it's important to understand what they mean.

If you aren't using ARC (still an option, even in iOS 5 and Lion) getters *can* be different depending on `retain`, `copy`, or `assign`.

`retain` and `copy` both look like:

```
- (NSString *)name {
    return [[name retain] autorelease];
}
```

`assign` is pretty basic, but is usually used more for weak references (like delegates):

```
- (id)delegate {
    return delegate;
}
```

I went into some detail on this because it's important to understand when using ARC, the code for all 3 look the same, but the behavior is still very much like what's written above. If you're using `atomic` instead of `nonatomic` then you need to add some locking/unlocking lines to make the method thread-safe. In any case, it's generally better to use the default accessors generated with `@synthesize` unless you want to do something really tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. The getter name dependce only of properties name.